# Why does np.var(x) and np.cov(x, y) give me different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm new to Python and was wondering why np.var(x) gives a different answer from the cov(x,x) values found in the output of np.cov(x, y). Shouldn't they be the same? I understand it has something to do with the bias or ddof, something about normalising it but I am not really sure what that means and could not find any resources that specifically answer my question. Hope someone can help!

Comment: refer stats book

Answer (score 2):

In numpy, cov defaults to a "delta degree of freedom" of 1 while var defaults to a ddof of 0. From the notes to numpy.var

```
Notes
-----
The variance is the average of the squared deviations from the mean,
i.e.,  ``var = mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)``.

The mean is normally calculated as ``x.sum() / N``, where ``N = len(x)``.
If, however, `ddof` is specified, the divisor ``N - ddof`` is used
instead.  In standard statistical practice, ``ddof=1`` provides an
unbiased estimator of the variance of a hypothetical infinite population.
``ddof=0`` provides a maximum likelihood estimate of the variance for
normally distributed variables.
```

So you can get them to agree by taking:

```
In [69]: cov(x,x)#defaulting to ddof=1
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5]])

In [70]: x.var(ddof=1)
Out[70]: 0.5

In [71]: cov(x,x,ddof=0)
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0.25,  0.25],
       [ 0.25,  0.25]])

In [72]: x.var()#defaulting to ddof=0
Out[72]: 0.25
```